# Add one column in existing table and load values for the required column only from csv file on the basis of ID in Liquibase

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I have a table `table1` with these columns and sample data:

| Id | Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | def |

I need to add a column and output will be like this after using below

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd">

    <changeSet id="add-date-column" author="gwylimwilliams">

        <addColumn tableName="table1">
             <column name="column2" type="date">
             </column>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

After using above schema, the new column will be added like this:

| Id | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |  |
| 2 | def |  |

You can see column 2 is empty, now I want to load this column value from a `.csv` file on the basis of `id`. I do not want to touch `column1` value. I know how to load data and uploadLoadData is there and we may use skip but how can we insert the condition or do we have any best way to implement this, we have all the column data in csv file and just want to insert column2 data on the basis of id

```
<changeset author="gwylimwilliams" id="update-column">
   <loadData
     file="abc.csv"
     seperator=","
     tableName = "table1" >
     <column name="column1" type="skip"/>
     <column name="column2" type="datetime"/>
   </loadData>
</changeset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `id` column is present in the table, then you can use `loadUpdateData`. Using `skip` works for me using Liquibase 3.10

```
<changeset author="gwylimwilliams" id="update-column">
   <loadUpdateData file="abc.csv" separator="," 
                   tableName = "table1" primaryKey="id">
     <column name="id"/>
     <column name="column1" type="skip"/>
     <column name="column2"/>
   </loadUpdateData>
</changeset>
```

Comment: will this not affect column1 value because csv file has data for all the columns and we want to update only column2 ?

Comment: @jitendravarshney: using `type="skip"` works for me.